# How to check if a class has any instance in Java?

Tags: java, class, instance

is there a way to find out if there already exists any instances in Java?

How can I have this function if there is any instance of a certain class, it will return true and return false if not.

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you are after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441984/how-can-i-know-whether-an-instance-of-a-class-already-exists-in-memory ?

Comment: That other Question is asking for what is known as the Singleton pattern, to create at most one instance. This Question is asking for a Boolean test: Are there any instances (one or more)?

Comment: This sounds a bit like an X-Y problem. What are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible unless you explicitly build it into your class by tracking when objects are constructed and garbage collected. For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final AtomicInteger instanceCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    public static boolean hasInstances() {
        return instanceCounter.get() > 0;
    }

    public MyClass(/*...*/) {
        //...
        instanceCounter.incrementAndGet();
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        try {
            super.finalize();
        } finally {
            instanceCounter.decrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}
```

But I have to admit, this has quite a pungent code smell. You might want to reconsider your requirements and see if this is really what you need to do.

Comment: I like it. AtomicInteger gives you thread-safety and the finalizer makes certain that you track when garbage collector reclaims it.

Comment: The final clause is key - here is how to solve the problem, but this is not a good problem to be solving in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Use a static variable. As one of the fields have an static int. Then in the constructor for the class increment that field. Since there will only be one instance of that field every time a new instance of the said object is created that field will increase by one.

Comment: @FredK Or you could use AtomicInteger (or similar). However, I don't think this exactly answers the question. What if an instance of our class gets garbage collected?

Answer (score 0):

Below you'll find a code snippet that uses JMX to inspect heap statistics and counts occurences of class instances given it's name (e.g. `"java.lang.Object"`). Use it only if no other option works for you. It's ugly and unstable. I cannot even guarantee it will work correctly on any JVM, but I've tested in on

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)
```

and

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Here's the code:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.ObjectName;

public class Utils {
    public static int getClassCount(String classFullyQualNane) throws Exception {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*\\d+:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\d+\\s*" + classFullyQualNane + "$");
        String histo = getClassHistogram(getMBeanServer());
        return Arrays.stream(histo.split("\\n")).filter(line -> pattern.matcher(line).matches()).mapToInt(line -> {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            matcher.matches();
            return Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        }).findAny().orElse(0);
    }

    private static String getClassHistogram(MBeanServer mBeanServer) throws Exception {
        ObjectName objectName = ObjectName.getInstance("com.sun.management:type=DiagnosticCommand");
        return (String) mBeanServer.invoke(objectName, "gcClassHistogram", new Object[] { new String[] {} },
                new String[] { String[].class.getName() });
    }

    private static MBeanServer getMBeanServer() {
        return ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    }

}
```

Comment: The Anarchist Cookbook ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of a **static variable**.
I am writing the code below:

```
public class MyClass{

static int counter=0;
MyClass(){
counter++;
}
public static boolean hasInstance(){
if(counter==0)
 return false;
else
return true;
 }
public static void main(String[] args)
 {System.out.println(MyClass.hasInstance());
MyClass obj=new MyClass ();
System.out.print(MyClass.hasInstance());

 }

}
```

Here the first statement will return **false** because we haven't created any instance of our class. But the second statement will return **true** because an instance has been created.

Output :

false

true